# Zend 1 radio option as image

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I want to show images as option label using Zend_Form_Element_Radio (Zend1). Something like this:

`$element->setMultiOptions(array(1=> '<img src="x.jpg">'));`

The expected output is to show the Image as the Label of the option. What would be the best way to do this.

I was able to disable escaping the Label of the Radio element by this line

`$form->$elName->getDecorator('label')->setOption('escape', false);`

But, looking for a way to achieve this effect for specific options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `escape=false` on the element, not just the decorator. Something like

```
$el = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('radio', array(
    'options' => $options,
    'escape' => false, // <- this is the line
));
```